# Como associar um Array em um textarea?

Tags: javascript

Como eu coloco o valor da const links para puxar da minha tag "textarea", o código funciona conforme esperado, roda no console certinho, porém quero que ao invés de colocar as informações na const links, o usuário possa colocar no campo de inpu "textarea" e apareça na tela. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```js
function myFunction() {

var elemento = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
const links = ['https://www.devs.com/produto/chave1', 'https://www.devs.com/produto/chave2'];

const chaves = links.map((link) => link.split('/')[link.split('/').length - 1]);
console.log(chaves);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a TEXTAREA element</h3>

Address:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea>

<p>Click the button to get the content of the text area.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O array seria digitado no mesmo formato que em uma expressão javascript? Se sim, dá para converter para json. Eval também seria uma opção se isso não representar uma ameça à segurança.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade pra alterar um pouco sua função mas acredito que resolva seu problema. Nesse caso é removido os dados da URL através de regex e mantido apenas a chave.

O `replace(/\n/g, '')` é apenas para remover as quebras de linha no caso do usuário escrever um item em cada linha, mas o código deve funcionar dos dois jeitos.

```
function myFunction() {
  let exibir = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  let urls = exibir.split(',');
  let chaves = [];
  urls.map(url => chaves.push(url.replace(/(.*?)produto\//g, '').replace(/\n/g, '')));
  console.log(chaves);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chaves[1];
}
```

Comment: Cara, consegui entender aqui, muito obrigado!